# Wordpress Update 5.5.3 has created a new db

Tags: wordpress

I have updated Wordpress to the latest version.
Once the update was finished, I had no more content on my site.
So I saw in PHPMyAdmin that Wordpress created a new db, with wp5s table prefix.
I still have the old table, what would be the best solution to use to recover all the data?

thank you very much for your help

Comment: Do you have a DB backup?

Comment: hi, yes, i have all old DB, but the prefix of the tables is different.
pointing WP to the old DB might be correct?

Comment: In config.php file and check $table_prefix  = 'prefixname';.

Comment: Yes, after update is "wp5s_" .

Comment: can i change the prefix and db and point to the old one? could be a good solution?

Comment: but why wordpress created this new DB? will it do so in every update? 
is it better for me to migrate to the new one?

Comment: Do you have any plugin for the DB?

Comment: I solved it by pointing to the old DB, I had no problems at all. Thanks!